# c# is not accepting var datatype

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, var

C# is not recognizing `var` "datatype"

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    var  lblNewsal = e.Row.FindControl("lblSalary") as Label;
    if (lblNewsal != null)
    {
        Total += int.Parse(lblNewsal.Text);
    }
}
```

Error is:

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   G:\ControlsExample\GridViewDemo\Default.aspx.cs 31 14
>   G:\ControlsExa‌​mple\GridViewDemo\

Comment: which version u r using?it is new feature of C# 3.0 .

Comment: Are you certain there is a server side `asp:label` with the id `lblSalary` on template you are binding to?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean "not recognizing"? Is there an error? Tell us the error.

Comment: yes not accepting var datatype

Comment: @gee.selvin1990 can you please post the error?

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) G:\ControlsExample\GridViewDemo\Default.aspx.cs 31 14 G:\ControlsExample\GridViewDemo\

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 = .NET 2.0 = does **NOT** know about `var` just yet! You need to upgrade to at least VS 2008. So you need to change your line to `Label lblNewsal = e.Row.FindControl("lblSalary") as Label;` and then you should be fine

Comment: is there any alternative for var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` keyword was introduced to C# 3.0 (Visual Studio 2008+), so *cannot* be used for .NET 2.0 and before (so anything before Visual Studio 2005 will not have support for it).

You need to either use the explicit type in that line:

```
Label lblNewsal = e.Row.FindControl("lblSalary") as Label;
```

Or upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade C# version,or just use `Label` rather than var